# How to speed up loading of data from three different tables and showing in a view pager with three fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

As I observed whatsapp load instantly reading from the local database of datas of three categories of chats, calls and contacts. I have three similar fragment of three categories as whatsapp inside viewpager. I need to first read and than sort the data as well. I see a significant amount of load time. 
Currently my approach is to read all the data from all three db and than sorting and hence loading the viewpager adapter.

What step can really improve my load time? Thanks a lot in advance for your answer.

Here is the code for reference

```
    class ReadDataAsync {
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> readDataFromDbTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            billsList.clear();

            itemList.clear();

            customerList.clear();

            billsList = snappyDbUtil.getAllBillsFromDB();

            itemList = snappyDbUtil.getArrayOfObjectFromKeys(DbName.ITEMS.name(), ItemEb.class);

            customerList = snappyDbUtil.getAllCustomersFromDB();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.i("time", "start time " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);


            Collections.sort(itemList, ItemEb.itemEbComparator);
            Collections.sort(customerList, CustomerEb.nameComparator);
            Collections.sort(billsList, BillEb.billsComparator);

            if (billsFragment != null)
                billsFragment.getBillsAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

            if (itemFragment != null)
                itemFragment.getItemsListAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

            if (contactsFragment != null)
                contactsFragment.getCustomerListAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();


            if (viewPagerAdapter != null) {
                mViewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            }
            Log.i("time", "stop time " + System.currentTimeMillis());


        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more information or show some code that would illustrate what you are doing now. It's not easy to determine the cause of what you _perceive_ to be excessive load time. But based on what you wrote, I would say you should do the ordering in the database queries instead to avoid sorting them afterward.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated with my code. I am using NoSQL db. Reading the data and sorting takes more time. Also if I load seperately in asynctask and than I have the problem with the viewpager adapter to refresh with the new data in list.

Comment: NoSQL databases rely heavily on good design in order for them to function correctly. At this point though we're all guessing as to your problem, use some profiling tools to help narrow down where your app is spending all its time. http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the link provided. It would be great if you could point me with link  of improving my NoSQL database than it would be great

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code I can only give very generic answers.

One thing I thought of was to make your database do your sorting for you by using `Order By` in your SQL

Another you definitely should be doing is reading from the database on a separate thread. [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is a good way to get started in Android threading if you're new to it

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have updated with my code. But going with different asynctask for all three data reading also not helping much.

Comment: You're still doing your sorting on the main thread. In your snappyDbUtil methods can you specify an order you'd like your values returned to you with?

Comment: are you talking about the order in which I can get which tables data base or few data of a table in particular order? I can do both

Comment: more specifically you're doing Collections.sort on the main thread

Comment: even if I remove sorting from main thread its taking time to load . The instantly load is not happing as it work in whatsapp.

Comment: we can keep trying to hit the lowest hanging fruit from your code sample, but you're going to have to profile the code and find the bottle necks. We can help more effectively if you can tell us exactly where all the time is going :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102806/discussion-between-sujeet-kumar-mehta-and-keith).